# How to differentiate between multiple POST buttons within the same form using BaseHTTPRequestHandler in Python?

Tags: python, httpserver, basehttprequesthandler

I have a form like so:

```
<form method="post">
    <div id="some-div">
        <input id="some-input" type="text" name="input" placeholder="some input">
        <button id="update-button" type="submit" name="submit_update_entry">Save changes</button>
        <button id="delete-button" type="submit" name="submit_delete_entry">Delete entry</button>
    </div>
```

In PHP I can use `isset($_POST['submit_update_entry'])` or `isset($_POST['submit_update_entry'])`.

I've already searched the internet and can only find solutions for Flask or Django. Also searched in class `BaseHTTPRequestHandler`, but with no luck.

EDIT: So I finally figured out how to do it. Apparently the button name is in `field_data = self.rfile.read(length)`, but when I parsed `field_data` to get the fields using `fields = parse.parse_qs(str(field_data,"UTF-8"))`, it was getting deleted. I had to change the line to `fields = parse.parse_qs(str(field_data,"UTF-8"), keep_blank_values=True)` to see `submit_update_entry` or `submit_delete_entry`.

Comment: What's wrong with using Flask or Django?

Comment: I'm trying to implement my own web server to learn about how they work.

Comment: Then I suggest you research on what exactly POST requests look like in terms of the content of the body and then use strings and lists to interpret the body.

Comment: I know what POST requests look like (e.g. "127.0.0.1 - - [09/Apr/2023 17:03:49] "POST /path.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -"). The issue is that the the button name field is never passed.

One alternative would be to modify the path to something like `/path/option1` or `path/option2` etc, but I don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured out how to do it. Apparently the button name is in

`field_data = self.rfile.read(length)`

but when I parsed `field_data` to get the fields using

`fields = parse.parse_qs(str(field_data,"UTF-8"))`

it was getting deleted. I had to change the line to

`fields = parse.parse_qs(str(field_data,"UTF-8"), keep_blank_values=True)`

to see `submit_update_entry` or `submit_delete_entry`.